# API Consumption Coldfusion

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I am trying to consume an api and trying to convert this code to codfusion

```
    <?php
       $client = new SoapClient( 
      "http://trial.black011.com/retailer/Black011SvcDemo.wsdl”,
      array(  "trace"      => 1,
              "exceptions" => 0)
            );               
    try {
    $arr = $client->recharge( ‘TestID, "TestPassword", "BKLD", “1234567890”,                                                             
                                              10, "Any Comment1 of You"  );

    echo 'error_code' . $arr['error_code'];
    echo 'error_msg' . $arr['error_msg'];
    echo 'tx_id' . $arr['tx_id'];
    echo 'comment1' . $arr['comment1'];

    }catch (SoapFault $exception) {
     echo "Error Code:" . $exception->getCode();
     echo "Error Message:" . $exception->getMessage();
   }
   ?>
```

I am using below code to consume the api

```
 <cfinvoke webservice="http://trial.black011.com/retailer/Black011SvcDemo.wsdl" method="recharge" returnvariable="res"  refreshwsdl="true" >

 <cfinvokeargument name="user_id" value="TestID">
 <cfinvokeargument name="passwd" value="TestPassword">
 <cfinvokeargument name="prod_id" value="BKLD">
 <cfinvokeargument name="mdn" value="1112223333">
 <cfinvokeargument name="amount" value="10">
 <cfinvokeargument name="comment1" value="10">
</cfinvoke>
```

I also tried this-

```
    <cfscript>
     ws = createObject("webservice",           "http://trial.black011.com/retailer/Black011SvcDemo.wsdl");
      writeDump(ws);
      result = ws.recharge( "TestID", "TestPassword", "BKLD", "19112223333", 10.00 );
      writeDump(result);
  </cfscript>
```

But every time I am trying, getting below error-

Web service operation recharge with parameters {} can not be found.
Could anybody see any problem with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a code and seems to be working as I tested it.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soapBody">
  <cfoutput>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:black011">
       <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
         <urn:recharge soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
          <user_id xsi:type="xsd:string">test</user_id>
          <passwd xsi:type="xsd:string">twawd</passwd>
          <prod_id xsi:type="xsd:string">"BKLD"</prod_id>
          <mdn xsi:type="xsd:string">"1234567890"</mdn>
          <amount xsi:type="xsd:float">20.0</amount>
          <comment1 xsi:type="xsd:string">"test"</comment1>
          </urn:recharge>
        </soapenv:Body>
       </soapenv:Envelope>
     </cfoutput>
   </cfsavecontent>
   <cfhttp url="http://trial.black011.com/retailer/OpenSvc.php" method="post" result="httpResponse">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="http://trial.black011.com/retailer/OpenSvc.php/recharge" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="no-compression" />
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim( soapBody )#" />
  </cfhttp>
  <cfif find( "200", httpResponse.statusCode )>
   <cfset soapResponse = xmlParse( httpResponse.fileContent ) />
   <cfdump var="#soapResponse#">
  </cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks @Preet, It worked for me, only to make little changes like removing quotes from values.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `ws` variable dump, method `recharge` takes 9 parameters:

```
recharge(java.lang.String, 
         java.lang.String, 
         java.lang.String, 
         java.lang.String, 
         float, 
         javax.xml.rpc.holders.StringHolder, 
         javax.xml.rpc.holders.StringHolder, 
         javax.xml.rpc.holders.StringHolder, 
         javax.xml.rpc.holders.StringHolder) returns void
```

Seems the code below works fine:

```
<cfscript>
    wsargs = {};
    wsargs.refreshwsdl = "Yes";
    ws = createObject("webservice", 
                      "http://trial.black011.com/retailer/Black011SvcDemo.wsdl",
                      wsargs);
    result = ws.recharge("TestID", 
                         "TestPassword", 
                         "BKLD", 
                         "19112223333", 
                         10.0, 
                         "test", 
                         "test", 
                         "test", 
                         "test");
</cfscript>
```

Hope this could help

Comment: According to wsdl, when I am trying to pass 6 variables it shows same error. but when I tried with nine, it does not show any error but return nothing too. In the documentation they said, it will return some data as I mentioned in my question above. Don't know what to do. Could you tell me how to get response??

Comment: It's possible you may need to JavaCast the javax.xml.rpc.holders.StringHolder argument maybe?  Not sure why the WSDL is ending up with that in the definition though.

Comment: According to `recharge` function dump it returns nothing, so in view of the discrepancy in wsdl and returned object definitions I think you should consult with API provider to get it clear.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you state you are specifing the method as follows

```
result = ws.recharge( "TestID", "TestPassword", "BKLD", "19112223333", 10.00 );
```

Which has 5 arguments.  The WSDL reads

```
<message name="rechargeRequest">
    <part name="user_id" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="passwd" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="prod_id" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="mdn" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="amount" type="xsd:float"/>
    <part name="comment1" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

There are 6 arguments.  You need to specify something for the 6th arguments, as typically with WSDLs the arguments help define the function in the same way as the function name does.  There aren't any optional arguments.  This gives the following which should work

```
result = ws.recharge( 
    "TestID", 
    "TestPassword", 
    "BKLD", 
    "19112223333", 
    10.00,
    "Some comment here"
);
```

Comment: I had a similar thought when I first saw this question. Strangely, the dumped method shows nine (9) arguments as [Sergey mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24586979/104223). Not sure why... From the wsdl, I would have expected to see six (6) as well.